# Warning SQL01271: The unnamed foreign key between tables [dbo].[Match] and [dbo].[Team] will be checked by checking the table

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010

I received this error while deploying a SQL Server DBProject

> DBProj.dbschema(0,0): Warning SQL01271: The unnamed foreign key
>   between tables [dbo].[Match] and [dbo].[Team] will be checked by
>   checking the table.  Name the foreign key to avoid checking the entire
>   table and only check the new constraint.

My table definition is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Match]
(
    MatchID         int identity(11,2) PRIMARY KEY, 
    TournamentID    int not null REFERENCES Tournament(TournamentID),
    Team1_ID        int not null REFERENCES Team(TeamID),
    Team2_ID        int not null REFERENCES Team(TeamID),
    MatchDate       date,
    MatchTime       time
)
```

What does this error means? What is the implication?

**update**

> actually, am concerned about the warning that it *will check the
>   entire table*. Is it at creation time or every time? how does this 
>   affect performance?

Comment: I tried your exact code and did not get any warnings!

Comment: It's from a DBProject created in visual studio. It helps manage the update of schema without dropping the tables. It resolves conflicts and display warnings like when "changing decimal to int" as "probably loss of precision" and the likes. This warning is one of such

Comment: It advised that references/constraints should be named.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Did you get the same result if you run the code from MSMS directly? I ran it from VS2010 and MSMS without warnings. This is strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the more verbose syntax

```
...
Team1_ID int not null CONSTRAINT FK_Match_Team1 FOREIGN KEY (TeamID) REFERENCES Team (TeamID),
Team1_ID int not null CONSTRAINT FK_Match_Team2 FOREIGN KEY (TeamID) REFERENCES Team (TeamID),
...
```

I'd suggest the lack of explicit constraint name is confusing VS because you have 2 match-team constraints. That is, it is a Visual Studio error not a SQL Server error. You won't get it in SSMS

Comment: actually, am concerned about the warning that it _will check the entire table_. Is it at creation time or every time records are added

Comment: @codingbiz: It will always happen when records are added or when Team records are deleted. However, VS could be braindead and check the entire table when you build or apply: I don't know because I use SSMS 100% for SQL Server work. It would seem unnecessary, but  see "braindead"...